# UITabBarController storyboard launch screen - initial tab?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I'm using a storyboard as my launch screen in my app, it contains a UITabBarController with 5 UINavigationControllers. The storyboard doesn't do anything but provide launch screens.

What I want to do is change the default selected tab. I'm currently stuck with this:[image: launch tab bar]

And once the actual view controllers load I get this:

[image: actual tab bar]

As you can imagine it's a bit jarring to have the selection jump like it does. I don't know how to change the tab programmatically since I cannot attach a custom class to anything in a launch screen. Of course, I don't really care if I do it for real, if there's a way to fake it with icons of different colors, that's fine as well, but the system adds that tint to selected icon.

Is there a way to do this with a storyboard launch screen? Thanks.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Use this piece of code in your view will appear method.
yourTabBarController.selectedViewController=[yourTabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2]

Comment: Because I'm using the storyboard as a launch storyboard I can't assign a custom subclass to any of the controllers, hence there is no viewWillAppear method for me to override.

Comment: ok you can try this 1. Select the tab bar controller in the storyboard 2. Show the Identity Inspector in the Utilities panel 3. Add a new "User Defined Runtime Attribute" 4. Set the Key Path to "selectedIndex" 5. Set the Type to "Number" 6. Set the Value to the index of the tab you wish to select (a value of 1 would select the second tab for example) 7. Save the Storyboard, build and run the application

Comment: Ah, that worked great! Thanks! For some reason I had to uncheck the "Use as Launch Screen" box to clear an error, but it still loaded the storyboard as my launch screen, go figure.

Comment: that does nothing in the launch screen storyboard

Comment: you cannot change your launch screen storyboard via code or runtime attributes.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use a tab bar controller in your LaunchScreen.storyboard. Instead use a normal view controller and add a tab bar, then add tab bar items as required. That seems to be the only way to make a tab bar without any index selected.

Answer (score 1):

Though this question was asked years ago, I've wrangled with it quite a bit and figured out a workaround that I'm satisfied with for my app TimeFinder.

The other answers here have made some good suggestions, but trying to build a replica of TabBarController sounds challenging and unsustainable, and I didn't have much luck with the User Defined Attributes hack mentioned by Akshay Agrawal [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYFgNm.png).

Since the problem is ultimately that the wrong item is shown as selected in the launch screen, I decided to **hide the selection entirely by changing the selected image tint color to light gray** to match the color of the other unselected tab bar item icons [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKHoKm.png).

This allowed me to copy and paste my project's top-level view controllers (view controllers embedded in navbarcontrollers embedded in a tabbarcontroller) into the Launch Screen storyboard, delete all the inessential connections and view controllers, and end up with a quality launch screen that makes the app appear to load faster than it does.

Here's my Launch Screen storyboard for reference [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrH4L.png), and here is my app which will have this launch screen update shortly [4](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/timefinder-hourly-planner/id1347447233?mt=8).

[TimeFinder on the App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/timefinder-hourly-planner/id1347447233?mt=8)

[image: Launch Screen Storyboard]
[image: Actual final view visible when app has finished loading]
[image: Launch Screen with modified Tab Bar Image Tint]
[image: Launch Screen with User-Defined Attribute hack]